Live USB boot problems
I've downloaded a Ubuntu 24.04 ISO and created a bootable USB in Windows 11 with etcher. I have a Dell XPS 13(3515). When booting from the USB drive, I get a grub command prompt. What can I do to install Ubuntu, I'm not interested in dual booting?
Edit:
I haven't installed Ubuntu, but believe I know the problem. My laptop has a UEFI BIOS and not a legacy BIOS.
Solved:
I used Rufus in windows to create the live bootable USB (used GPT/non-CSM options).

For best advice, please be specific with details. You mention a Ubuntu 24.04 LTS ISO, but don't actually say which (as there are many available), eg. the installer used is chosen at download time, as Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Server uses the subiquity installer, Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Desktop uses the ubuntu-desktop-installer, and the various 24.04 LTS flavors use either ubuntu-desktop-installer or calamares. Whilst you likely don't mean a flavor, you still have options.  Did you verify ISO after download?  https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0
